# How to Select a substring in Oracle SQL for specific length only

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am having below values from the column

- Q6wabc89WmrtUX2pNYRnwjInCAT9ZxvaY7N7KAG440360130
- Q6wabc89WmrtUX2pNYRnwwjInCAT9ZxvaY7N7KAG4a403648jInCAT9ZxvaY7N7KwjInCAT9ZxvaY7N7AG4403601AGd4s197

Length of first value is 48.

Length of second value is 97.

Now condition is if the length is 97 of any value then use first 48 characters only else use what ever exists.

A SUBSTR function is already there

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CLNT_ID,0,48) FROM CLNT;
```

which is working fine, Now I want to use this only in case where the length of value is equal to 97.

This Select statement is part of one store procedure.
Please assist to identify right query for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The first string is 48 characters long, while the second string is 100 characters long - but not 97. Could you explain what do you mean by: `The second value is having length of 97` ?.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Still the second value is 100 characters length but not 97, see this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a68e50/2. I vote to close this question as unclear.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong I double checked before pasting the value. Thanks

Comment: When you run `select length('Q6wabc89WmrtUX2pNYRnwwjInCAT9ZxvaY7N7KAG4a403648jInCAT9ZxvaY7N7KwjInCAT9ZxvaY7N7KAG4403601AG4403s197')
from dual` then Oracle says that the length is `100` but not `97` as you wrote, this is wrong and misleading.

Comment: Seems this time its OK, as I just checked count is coming 97 for value in question. Q6wabc89WmrtUX2pNYRnwwjInCAT9ZxvaY7N7KAG4a403648jInCAT9ZxvaY7N7KwjInCAT9ZxvaY7N7AG4403601AGd4s197 Use this https://www.lettercount.com/

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way is to use `length()`:

```
select (case when length(clnt_id) = 97
             then substr(clnt_id, 1, 48)
             else clnt_id
        end)
from clnt;
```

This would seem to be the simplest implementation of the logic.  Also note that the second argument for `substr()` counts from "1" not "0", so you should use "1" there (the effect is the same).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
case 
  when regexp_like (CLNT_ID , '^[[:alnum:]]{97}$') 
  then SUBSTR(CLNT_ID,0,48) 
  else null 
end label1, CLNT_ID
FROM CLNT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this way,

```
SELECT CASE SIGN( LENGTH(:p_text) - 97 )
            WHEN -1 THEN
                :p_text
            ELSE
                SUBSTR(:p_text, 1, 48)
       END
  FROM dual;
```